# When running build runner on flutter I get the following error

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

When I run

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

I get the following error.

```
    Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.40.6/lib/error/error.dart:7:8: Error: Error when reading '../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/_fe_analyzer_shared-12.0.0/lib/src/base/errors.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:_fe_analyzer_shared/src/base/errors.dart';
```

Comment: try
`flutter pub cache repair`, `flutter clean`, `flutter pub upgrade`.

Comment: Shukran, Hamed. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
```